# Android selecting two files from listview

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i have the code to show the files of SD card in a listview with checkboxes. it might loads the full files instead of just their path ! i want the user to select two files and then get the files path to inputstream to merge them to a third one.

The code is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.joiner;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button mButton;
    private List<Model> list;
private ListView mainListView ;
 public String msg="kumkum";
 File[] sdDirectories;
 ArrayList<String> planetList;
 private List<File> h;




 ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter ;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
        //mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                int temp;
                //Model[] a=(Model[]) list.toArray();
                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                {
                    Model b=list.get(i);
                    if(b.isSelected())
                    {
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, b.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        for(int counter=0;counter<sdDirectories.length;counter++)
                        {
                            if(b.getName().equals(sdDirectories[counter].getName()))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,sdDirectories[counter].getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                h.add(sdDirectories[counter]);
                                //h.get(0).getPath();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }



        });
        String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        //you may also want to add (...|| Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)
        //if you are only interested in reading the filesystem
        if(!extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no sd card found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else{




            planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
            planetList.add("wajeeh");



            //for(int i=0;i<sdDirectories.length;i++)
            //planetList.add(sdDirectories[i].getName());



            planetList.add(msg);

            adapter = new Inadopter(MainActivity.this,getModel());



// Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
            mainListView.setAdapter( adapter );



          }
    }
    private List<Model> getModel() {
        list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        list.add(get("Linux"));
        list.add(get("a"));
        // Initially select one of the items
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        FileFilter MP3ANDdirectoryOnly = new FileFilter() {
            private String getExtension(File f) {
                String ext = null;
                String s = f.getName();
                int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

                if (i > 0 &&  i < s.length() - 1) {
                    ext = s.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
                }
                return ext;
            }

            public boolean accept(File file) {
                if(file.isDirectory()||!file.isHidden())
                    return true;

                String extension = getExtension(file);
                if (extension != null||!file.isHidden()) {
                    if (extension.equals("mp3"))
                        {
                            return true;
                    }
            }
                return false;
        }};
        sdDirectories = sd.listFiles(MP3ANDdirectoryOnly);
        for(int i=0;i<sdDirectories.length;i++)
            list.add(get(sdDirectories[i].getName()));


        list.get(1).setSelected(true);
        return list;
      }
    private Model get(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Model(s);
    }
}
```

`

> InAdapter.java

```
    package com.example.joiner;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Inadopter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

  private final List<Model> list;
  private final Activity context;

  public Inadopter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.simpleroow, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
  }

  static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
      view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.simpleroow, null);
      final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
      viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
      viewHolder.checkbox
          .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
              Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                  .getTag();
              element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

            }
          });
      view.setTag(viewHolder);
      viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
      view = convertView;
      ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    return view;
  }
}
```

I need to get the path of two files and send it to this code

```
public class ConcateSongActivity extends Activity {
    Button mbutt;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mbutt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Click_Karo);
        mbutt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                try {
                    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/viv0.wav");
                    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/viv1.wav");
                    SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(fis1,fis2);


                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/vis.wav"));

                    int temp;

                    try {
                        while ((temp = sis.read())!= -1){

                            fos.write(temp);

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the feedback link changes to the question "Was this post usefull to you?" as soon as I try to click it, I see no other way than to put a question here in the place reserved for answers.

What is exactly your problem? Can't you extract two paths or cant you merge two files?

Comment: In onclick() you loop through the list. If b.isSelected() then b.getName() gives the name. Add the directory to it. You need only two b.isSelected(). My earlier answer is removed by Bill the Lizard. I would like to know why. My answer was to the point and I had already explained the 'feedback problem'.